# Find the last not empty row in a range of cells holding a formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

How can I find the last row in a range of cells that hold a formula, where the result of the formula is an actual value and not empty?

Say in a simplified way that the range of cells `("E1:E10")` hold a formula referring to cells A1 through A10 as followed `=IF("A1"="","","A1")`. But only the cells A1 through A6 have a value filled in, so the result of the formula for cells E7 through E10 will be empty.

Trying to do it with:

```
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

results in lastRow having the value of `10`. What I want is for the value of lastRow to be `6` in this example.

The actual code is way more complex than this so I can't just check for the last filled in Row of Column A, as the formulas refer to single cells on different sheets and are added dynamically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that more elegant way than was provided by `@D_Bester` is to use `find()` option without looping through the range of cells:

```
Sub test()
    Dim cl As Range, i&
    Set cl = Range("E1:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
    i = cl.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    Debug.Print "Last row with data: " & i
End Sub
```

test

[image]

**Also, more shorter version of the code which was provided above is:**

```
Sub test2()
    Debug.Print [E:E].Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
End Sub
```

Comment: Works great and was more what I was looking for.
I just have one question, what is the meaning of the ampersand `&` in the declaration of the variable `i`? (As it seems to work just the same without the ampersand)

Comment: @Pascale it means `Dim i as Long`, if you will remove `&` then `i` will be declared `as Variant`. It just a shorthand method of coding, e.g. `%` is `Integer`, `&` is `Long`, `$` is `String`, `@` is `Currency`, `!` is `Single`,  `#` is `Double`, if not specified then `Variant`

Comment: @Vasily, thanks for giving me the whole list of shorthand declarations and -1 to Micrososft for not including them in their general [Declaring Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264241.aspx) page

Comment: This answer is elegant! Россия красиво

Answer (score 5):

You want to find the last cell in a column that is not empty AND is not a blank string("").

Just follow the LastRow with a loop checking for a non-blank cell.

```
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Do
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, 5).Value <> "" Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    lastrow = lastrow - 1
Loop While lastrow > 0

If lastrow > 0 Then
    Debug.Print "Last row with data: " & lastrow
Else
    Debug.Print "No data in the column"
End If
```

Notice that your `Rows.count` does not specify which sheet. That means it will use the active sheet. Of course `ActiveSheet.Range()` also is on the active sheet. But it is bad practice to mix `Range` or `Rows` with `.Range` or `.Rows`. It indicates a thoughtless usage that could bite you if you changed the `ActiveSheet` but didn't change the unspecified reference.

Comment: I had already thought about looping through them backwards like you suggest, but was hoping for a more elegant way to achieve it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and thank you for explaining how to improve the use of Rows.Count and ActiveSheet.

Comment: I think there is, try using the "divide and conquer" approach. As `2^20` is equal to 1048576. That is the value of `Rows.Count`. That said your `Do...Loop` will never repeat more than 20 times to reach the `lastrow`.

Comment: @D_Bester there is another option to find the last non blank cell using `find()` option, withot looping through the range

Answer (score 2):

This should help you determine the last row containing a formula (in column `A` on sheet1 `Sheet1`):

```
lastRow  = Split(Split(Sheet1.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Address, ",")(UBound(Split(Sheet1.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Address, ","))), "$")(2)
```

`SpecialCells` is used to determine the range of all the cells containing a formula. This range is then parsed using `Split`. With `Ubound` the last of these cells is being retrieved. The result is being split again to extract the row number.

Comment: I tried to apply your code but it returns the first row having a formula in it. (The range in my sheet is from row 3 to row 26 and your lastRow returns 3: when I print it out with MsgBox, when I expected it to be 21) Not sure what i need to adjust or even if this is a good approach. You say "This should help you determine the last row containing a formula" but i need the last row containing a formula where the result of that formula is not "" (empty string). Sorry if I misunderstood your answer but I have no experience with vba at all so I am totally relying on what i find on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Ralph The Address property is limited to a 255-character string, and so may not include all of the areas containing formulas.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function returnLastRow()
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    returnLastRow = .Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    End With
End Function
```