# Find the last not empty column in a range where cells may contain a formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that acts as a drawing register.

The first 5 columns make up the drawing name/number.  I place the revision number of the drawing in each subsequent column. Some of these columns appear blank, but have formulas for other functions in the worksheet.

I would like the first column after the drawing name/number (col F in this case) to display the latest revision number.

Essentially this means I need a formula (or VBA code) to search for the last non-empty cell in a row, but ignoring cells that have formulas in them (that appear blank).

[Find the last not empty row in a range of cells holding a formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971250/find-the-last-not-empty-row-in-a-range-of-cells-holding-a-formula) is very similar but refers to the last row in a column (I am looking for the last column in a row). I couldnt adapt it. I think my syntax was incorrect.

To mention a few extra points:

1. The revisions are alphanumeric
2. The revisions are in pairs (as each drawing has a status code and revision, both of which are alphanumeric) and in the first 2 columns (F and G) I need to show the latest status and revision respectively.  The status and revision are placed in adjacent columns on the same row each time. So in reality I need a formula that will return the last 2 non-empty columns and the formula needs to ignore cells that contain formulas that return a blank value.
3. I have tried various combinations of Lookup (similar to Ron's response below), index and VBA code as shown in the above link.  If possible I would like to keep it as a formula but I am not adverse to using VBA.
4. The formula only needs to apply to an individual row, but needs to be copied down as each separate drawing is on a new row.

Comment: You need to do this in every row, or in general for one row?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the revision number might be either text or numeric, you can try:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN($G5:$XFD5)>0),$G5:$XFD5)
```

Comment: this formula works well until i get to my first blank cell. once i locate my target range past a blank cell it ignores the values before the blank cell.  i am not sure why, i have tried various versions of this formula.  is there an edit to this formula that could work? (note when i say blank cell, some cells are empty and others have formulas that return blank values). an alternative would be if i could assign multiple ranges to this formula - i.e. just select the cells that will be populated with alphanumeric info? i cannot seem to break up the target range, only select a large single one

Comment: @shay I don't understand.  The formula is designed to find the last cell in a row that is not blank. (Where  blank means `LEN(cell_displayed_contents)=0`, which will be the case whether the blank is due to nothing in the cell, or a formula displaying nothing).  If that is not what you want, you will need to clarify and provide an example by editing your original question.  Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ron, you are of course correct.  my 'blank cells' were actually returning a value of zero, and i had turned off the 'display zero value' in worksheet settings.  once i updated my formulas your proposal worked perfectly.  Do you have a version of this formula that will do exactly the same but return the second last cell - i.e. the cell value immediately before the last non-blank cell? just to note (if it helps), the second last cell will always be non-blank. Much appreciated.

Comment: @shay You would merely offset `result_vector` by one.  For example:  `=LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN($G5:$XFD5)>0),$F5:$XFC5)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try (in F1 and copied down to suit):

```
=INDEX(G1:Z1,MATCH(1E+100,G1:Z1))
```

`Z` may be increased if you expect to require more columns.

Formulae that return blanks should be ignored by the above.

Comment: thanks, this only seems to work for alpha or numeric. i need one that works for alphanumeric.  i have updated the question to confirm this parameter.