# merging different sheets into one with the same structure

Tags: excel, vba

I Have some sheets and a "Consolidated Pipeline" sheet in which i have to merge all the other sheets.
I just need to copy all the data from every sheet in the consolidated one, one after the other.

I have a problem with the function that find the last non-empty row to understand where to append the data in the consolidated sheet but it seems that the last row returned is always the very last row of the document, not the last non-empty one

this is the function

```
Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(what:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row                          
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: What is your data like? Are there formulas that return a blank string `""`?

Comment: Yes, some formula could return string ""

Comment: Note that your code approach considers any cells that are populated, which would include cells with formulas returning a blank string.

Comment: How can I avoid those cells?

Comment: [One approach here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35486695/how-do-i-find-the-last-row-that-contains-data-where-cells-may-contain-empty-text).

Comment: [Another here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971250/find-the-last-not-empty-row-in-a-range-of-cells-holding-a-formula).